# How to see paging results with Sequel and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, will-paginate, sequel

I am using `will_paginate` and attempting to page a dataset from Sequel. The requires are:

```
require 'will_paginate'
require 'will_paginate/sequel'
require 'will_paginate/collection'
require 'will_paginate/version'
require 'sequel/extensions/pagination'
```

The Ruby code is:

```
get '/candidate' do
     @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).extension(:pagination).paginate(1, 10)
     erb :candidate
end
```

In the view: `<%= will_paginate @items %>`

The dataset renders correctly with 10 records and when I click "2" or "Next" the address in the browser changes to `http://localhost:4567/candidate?page=2` but the records remain the same. Effectively, the results are not paged and I cannot get past page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers for the page and the number of records are hardcoded in your example using `paginate(1, 10)`, so it will always bring back page 1 with 10 records. You need to pass on the `page=2` parameter from the query-string. This is done via the [`params` helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers):

```
get '/candidate' do
  @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(:page => params["page"].to_i, :per_page => 10)
  erb :candidate
end
```

If you wanted, you could also pass on the `per_page` in the query-string by adding this code:

```
get '/candidate' do
   @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(:page => params["page"].to_i, :per_page => params["per_page"].to_i)
   erb :candidate
end
```

I'd add a default for both in case they're not given. I understand [you can do this via the library](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use), e.g. `WillPaginate.per_page = 10`, but you could also do this in the route, via:

```
get '/candidate' do
  page = params.fetch "page", 1
  per_page = params.fetch "per_page", 10
  @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(:page => page.to_i, :per_page => per_page.to_i)
  erb :candidate
end
```

---

I didn't notice before you were also using the Sinatra helper provided by will_paginate.

I'd either call `paginate` on the dataset *or* get a dataset,  unpaginated,  and pass it  to the helper. So either this:

```
get '/candidate' do
  page = params.fetch "page", 1
  per_page = params.fetch "per_page", 10
  @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(:page => page.to_i, :per_page => per_page.to_i)
  erb :candidate
end

# in the view
<%= @items %>
```

or this:

```
get '/candidate' do
  @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id)
  erb :candidate
end

# in the view
<%= will_paginate @items, params %>
```

---

So, from [what I can see](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/v3.0.4/lib/will_paginate/sequel.rb), the Sequel `paginate` method is not overwritten or wrapped/overloaded, so [its method signature](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-paginate) is the same as it would be if you were just using Sequel and not will_paginate as well. Which means that this code worked for me:

```
require 'will_paginate'
require 'will_paginate/sequel'
get '/candidate' do
  page = params.fetch "page", 1
  per_page = params.fetch "per_page", 10
  @items = Repo.db[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(page.to_i, per_page.to_i)
  haml :candidate
end
```

In the Haml view:

```
- @items.each do |i|
  = i[:title]
```

Since the method signature is the same I'm not sure what advantage you gain from using will_paginate over Sequel's paginate at all. I couldn't find a way to get the Sinatra helper to work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately it does not work, error message is: 
ArgumentError at /candidate
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

    file: pagination.rb
    location: paginate
    line: 26

I have had this before with my various experiments, I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: @user1903663 Unfortunately there are only 25 lines in the that file! Take out `.extension(:pagination)`, it's not needed, see if that helps. e.g. `@items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)`.

Comment: sorry to be a complete pain but still no good. This time, error is: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

    file: pagination.rb - same error message, in fact.
    location: paginate
    line: 26

Comment: @user1903663 Add your versions of Ruby, Sequel, Sinatra, and will_paginate to the question and I'll see if I can recreate it.

Comment: @user1903663 I also noticed something about the question, I've added it in an edit to the answer.

Comment: thanks, sorry for delay. ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux], sequel 3.48.0, Sinatra/1.4.2

Comment: Thanks, I tried (all) above and none works. The last suggestion produces: undefined method `total_pages' for #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset:0x8c8ea08>

Comment: I have, however, managed to get paging working with active record but now I am failing to do join queries with activerecord, so I have the absurd situation where I am using activerecord for paging and sequel for everything else. Talk about schizophrenic! Your help still needed, therefore.

Comment: @user1903663 Yes, that will certainly get confusing soon! What's the will_paginate version? I saw [this error](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Troubleshooting#im-getting-undefined-method-total_pages-error-when-rendering-in-the-view) and maybe it's related?

Comment: will_paginate 3.0.4, many thanks and good luck, yes I have seen the above error posting too, afraid it does not help.

Comment: @user1903663 I've updated the answer with what worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Iain, thanks for all your work on this. While your solution gets me a rendered page with ten rows, when I click to page 2 I still get the error that plagued me before which is: undefined method `-' for "2":String ... Oh dear. I will continue, for the time being, using both active record and sequel which is ridiculous but ...

Comment: @user1903663 Did you change the Haml I gave to ERB? I should've used ERB, my apologies, I don't use it myself and I must've been in autopilot.

Comment: I did change to erb, thank you. But still it working. I get the first page but subsequent clicks, to next page(s), produce an error. I do still want to find a solution though as I don't want to continue to use Active Record and Sequel together.

Comment: yep, undefined method `-' for "2":String

Comment: @user1903663 Ah, I've got it (answering after a coffee helps:) All querystring parameters come back as strings, so you need to cast numbers to integers etc. The first page works because you don't send the params for the first page and it uses a default. Try …`.paginate(page.to_i, per_page.to_i)` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: FANTASTIC, you are a scholar and a gentleman. thank you. Works perfectly. Like so: 
  page = params.fetch "page", 1
  per_page = params.fetch "per_page", 10
  @items = DB[:candidates].order(:id).paginate(page.to_i, per_page.to_i)
I have given it a "tick". Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1903663 Glad I could help. I've updated the answer too, if anyone else gets the same problem they won't have to read all our comments! :)